# readonly field django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Cómo hacer un **form field solo lectura (readonly)** en django
si tengo un select en el form de tipo **ModelChoiceField**, y en el **Model** equivale a un atributo tipo **ForeignKey** estado tratando con esto pero no funciona:

```
class CostoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    """
    Edicion de Costos con formset.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Costo
        exclude = ('user', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CostoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.template = 'crispy_template/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('DELETE', css_class='btn btn-primary')
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', _('Aceptar')))
        self.fields['destination'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: Muchas veces depende de si usas un plugin del lado del front para renderizar los selects, los cuales para activar el `readonly` o el `disabled` no dependen del atributo `readonly` o `disabled` (según sea el caso) de la etiqueta de html. Si no de atributos mismos del plugin o el manejador en javascript.

Comment: no men la verdad acabo de realizar un testeo sencillo en un nuevo proyecto sin nada de plugins ni estilos y pues tampoco solo me deja aplicar el **disabled** pero no el **readonly**  ;(

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes usar es `Disabled` que que hara que el usuario no puede seleccionar el campo: sera como lo siguinete:

```
self.fields['destination'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

Aquí habra que ver que cuando el usuario envie el formulario para guardar ese campo lleve un valor pero como no especificar si el usuario guardara o no, lo anterior creo que resuelve tu pregunta

Comment: si amigo eso lo intente pero el problema es que al desactivarlo los datos siguen llegando al template lo que hace que el tiempo de carga siga igual como tengo muchos datos a relacionar en ForeignKey y eso es lo que no quiero

Comment: lo que quieres es que no lleguen los datos al template? que sea un select vacio?

Comment: pues no vació sino que muestre el valor relacionado solo lectura

Comment: Al intentar en modelAdmin con readonly_field si funciona como lo deseo por ende debe existir una manera para model forms

Answer (score 0):

un select ya de por si es de solo lectura ya que no puedes introducir texto solo te lo muestra y aunque pudieras poner que sea "de solo lectura" esto no hace que no se carguen todos los datos.

te sugiero crear un `widget` de tipo `TextInput` para mostrar este valor

```
class CostoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    destination2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attr={'readonly': True}), max_length= 100)
    class Meta:
        model = Costo
        exclude = ('user', 'destination')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CostoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.template = 'crispy_template/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('DELETE', css_class='btn btn-primary')
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', _('Aceptar')))
```

para añadir el valor relacionado tienes que hacerlo desde el `View`

```
class CostoView(FormView):

    model = Costo
    form_class = CostoForm
    .....
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CostoView, self).get_initial()
        if self.object.destination:
             initial['destination2'] = self.object.destination.name

    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este código a continuación estoy comprobando si el usuario es del grupo Personal para mostrarle o no campos. Puede que te sirva.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import TuModelo    


class TuModeloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
readonly_fields = ('created', 'updated')
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="Personal").exists():
        return ('created', 'updated', 'key','name')
    else:
        return ('created', 'updated')

admin.site.register(TuModelo, TuModeloAdmin)
```